# Why is my input source not changing when I send the <Active Source> message via CEC-Client?

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi, hdmi-cec

### Problem/Question

When I use CEC-Client to send the active source command to switch the TV input to a particular source, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

### Environment

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian plugged into a Vizio TV. I've installed cec-client (via cec-utils), and I'm running commands using it from within Bash on the Raspberry Pi.

Here is the scan of the CEC bus of my setup:

```
CEC bus information
===================
device #0: TV
address:       0.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Unknown
osd string:    TV
CEC version:   1.3a
power status:  on
language:      eng


device #1: Recorder 1
address:       4.0.0.0
active source: yes
vendor:        Pulse Eight
osd string:    CECTester
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      eng


device #4: Playback 1
address:       1.0.0.0
active source: no
vendor:        Unknown
osd string:    Roku
CEC version:   1.4
power status:  on
language:      ???


currently active source: Recorder 1 (1)
```

### What I have tried:

A lot of things.
More specifically:

- `tx 1f:82:10:00`
- `tx 1f 82 10 00`
- (*a bunch of stuff with wrong addresses*)

  - *e.g. `tx 4f:82:10:00` and `tx 10:82:10:00`*
- `sp 1.0.0.0`
- `spl 4`
- reading the [HDMI specification regarding active source messages on CEC](http://bfiles.chinaaet.com/whpt/blog/20170919/1000008562-6364143185282736974850538.pdf#page=251)

### Other Info

- I know that the TV supports it, because the device that I am trying to switch to (a Roku) uses CEC to switch inputs to itself when I start using its remote. Watching CEC-Client when it does this, it sends `4f:82:10:00` to declare itself as the active source, which is exactly what I've tried except with itself as the initiator (which I've also tried just in case).
- To make sure that the `tx` command was working, I used it to successfully send the TV into standby.
- Using `as` to set the Pi as the active source works fine, but the corresponding tx command, `tx 1f:82:40:00`, does nothing (even though the output of CEC-Client shows it using the exact same message).
- I have only listed the CEC-Client commands above, but I have tried them all both directly in the CEC-Client's interactive prompt and by echoing it into cec-client (i.e. `echo "tx 1F:82:10:00" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1`).

### Where I'm At

Any help/feedback would be greatly appreciated! I'm at my wits' end, and can't think of anything else to try that I haven't already.

(Also any feedback on my question is welcome; I'm still pretty new to posting on the StackExchange network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out setting the type (`-t` or `--type`) when launching the cec-client is necessary for me. It seems like `-t t` and `-t p` are the best working options. It's still super finicky (or I would do more testing to post a more deterministic answer).

I'm going with setting the type to tuner (`t`) as it allows me to switch input, and doesn't prevent me from changing the volume on my TV with the remote like audio (`a`) did, yet it is still a device type that I won't be plugging in to my TV, so I don't have to worry about getting it confused or anything. I may eventually switch to playback (`p`) in the future if that seems to help with anything. Explicitly setting recorder (`r`) actually also worked once, but I think the TV still thought it was an audio device (since I still couldn't change the volume. It took me a while and a lot of fiddling to fix that...).

(If anyone knows why this is necessary, even though using the built-in `as` command works without specifying the type at launch, or more detail on the effects of changing the type, I'll accept their answer.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for bothering to answer your own question! I was struggling with the same, and playing with the type put me on the right track.